# Docker on VPS and allowing access only through specific IP address with iptables

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, iptables, docker

I'm trying to setup Docker on a VPS and make all containers running on various ports available only to my IP address. This is only meant to be used for development purposes.

Simplest setup to proove the concept is running `nginx` container on port `80`. I want to block all access to this container except my IP (let's call it 123.123.123.123).

Since Docker edits iptables directly and has some forwarding rules, none of the solutions I tried really worked. Either the traffic is completely blocked or is still accessible from any IP address.

What is the correct setup that will lock everyting down only to my IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert either, learning iptables for myself right now.
But given this is the rule set by docker on your host:

```
user@server:~# sudo iptables -L FORWARD

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

You can insert a new rule in front of the DOCKER* targets.
This would need to drop packages not originating from your ip.

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s ! 123.123.123.123 -j DROP
```

Although working on the FORWARD chain you should use the command iptables-apply to avoid locking yourself out if you are like me not very familiar with iptables.

iptables-apply works with config files instead.

```
sudo iptables -L > config.v4
<edit file>
sudo iptables-apply config.v4
```

Your new rule
-A FORWARD ! -s 62.157.38.52 -j DROP

should go right before
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER

If this restriction should only be made to docker then you could also add it to your DOCKER-USER chain instead.